# "Money is all what/that I need."

Tags: adverbs, determiners, clauses, relative-clauses, construction

- 1.) *Money is* ***all that*** *I need.*
- 2.) *Money is* ***all what*** *I need.*

Which one is right? or which one have you not ever seen? and is there any difference between them?

But, what about the following?

- If we consider the word ***"all"*** as an **adverb**, not as a **noun**, what would you like to say?

(**In addition:** I am wondering the reason why my question is labeled as an answered question, because if you look at it you will notice that they are not the same at all.)

Comment: Look [here](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=1556644), nima. Though we don't usually respond to such basic questions ; ELL is a better choice.

Comment: I'm curious as to what the answer is too. *[shrugs]* -- That expression ("all what") could possibly be parsed as different types of constructions, depending on the context (and possibly grammar). *"Money is all what she wants"* is also interesting. In general, "all" could be a determiner, or a fused determiner-head, and as to which it is might be ambiguous. The word "what" could be an interrogative word, or a fused relative. Put them together ("all what"), and it might become ambiguous indeed, and perhaps not so easy to generalize.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

[image]
Money is all that I need- indicates that as of now you need money to complete the activity/task you are intended to do. 
Money is all what I need- indicates greed for money that is, all you need is money and you don't care for feelings or such thing.

@nima_persian I am attaching an image that shows how to use That and What. See whether it's useful or it gives the reason you asked for.

Comment: 'Money is all what I need' - indicates a poor command of the English language.

Comment: The down voter was real fast! Pooja, try to find something supporting your answer to prevent such down voting.

Comment: both are right grammatically and both have meanings in their own way.

Comment: This answer is in no way correct.

Comment: Thanks. But, my professor that his the famous professor in my country has said to me that the second one is not correct.

Comment: In addition, I would like the reason.